# Three.js: Move transition and Sequence action

Tags: three.js

I am working on a WebGL application using Three.JS library.

I am trying to load Blender 3d model into my Three.js application in a Scene and try to navigate between one scene to another. I am able to successfully load blender 3d model js file into the scene and it shows the model properly in my Three.js based project.  I am having the following requirements now, and unable to get it done.

1. When i'm loading one scene to another scene, i want to do some kind of move transition from one scene to another. How to achieve camera move transition like frontwards, backwards, right and left side ways through programmatically.
2. How to achieve 'Sequence actions' like when camera moving frontwards and reaching a place, it will load and show the next scene. I think, we can achieve this using 
   'Sequence actions' in opengl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@zz85 has created an excellent `Director` class that enables chaining patterns like the following:

```
director = new THREE.Director();

director
.addAction( 0, function() {
    camera.position.set( 750, 850, 750 );
})
.addAction( 10, function() {
    // do something
    doSomething();
})
.addAction( 10, function() {
    // top view
    camera.position.set( 0, 1000, 0 );
})
// cross the terrain
.addTween( 18, 4, camera.position, {}, { x:300 , y: 80, z: -2000 }, 'cubicInOut' )
.addTween( 18, 4, camera, { lens: 35 }, { lens: 100 }, 'cubicInOut', function( k ) {
    camera.setLens( camera.lens );
})
.addTween( 18, 4, lookAt, {}, { x:300 , y: 80, z: 2000 }, 'linear' )

})
.addAction( 80, function() {
    stop();
});
```

Demo: http://jabtunes.com/labs/boidsnbuildings/

Blog post: http://www.lab4games.net/zz85/blog/2012/11/19/making-of-boids-and-buildings/

This demo uses three.js. r.54dev, but I expect it will work with the current version, three.js r.58.

Another option is to use [Tween.js](https://github.com/sole/tween.js/), but based on your requirements, I expect `Director` would be your preference.

Example: http://threejs.org/examples/canvas_interactive_cubes_tween.html

three.js r.58

Comment: Hi WestLangley,Thanks for sharing the solution.It really helps. But, I need some more help, 1.) Could you please share me the complete sample project which uses this Director class approach for moving transition? Need full source to go through and understand it. 2.)Please advise, How can i load the next scene dynamically when the move fron transition is finished? Appreciate your help on this!

Comment: 1. I do not own it, so I am not able to give it to you. The source is available at the site I referenced. For example, http://jabtunes.com/labs/boidsnbuildings/Director.js. 2. Use the `.addAction()` method of `Director`. Sorry, I can't write your code for you, but I can answer questions about three.js.