# Using three.js with time series data

Tags: javascript, opengl-es, three.js, webgl

How do you best go about using time series data to direct the animation of a three.js scene?

For example:

```
  Time     | ObjA(x,y,z) | ObjB(x,y,z) | ...
  00:00:00 | 0,9,0       | 1,1,1       | ...
  00:00:10 | 0.1,0,0.1   | 1,0.5,1     | ...
  00:00:15 | 0.1,0.1,0.1 | 0.9,0.5,1   | ...
```

The data can be hundreds, if not thousands of lines long. And the number of object can also change from dataset to dataset.

I've read up on using tween.js and chaining keyframes. But creating and chaining many thousands of tweens during initialization doesn't feel like the right answer.

Is tween.js the right way to go? Or have I missed an extension that would better handle the situation? Any examples of a similar use case that could prove useful?

**UPDATE**

So [Director.js](https://github.com/zz85/ThreeLabs/blob/master/Director.js) would certainly be capable of giving the right result. But it looks like it was intended to tween camera motion around a scene rather that directing the motion of hundreds of meshes. Is chaining potentially thousands of tweens together on possibly hundreds of meshes the best way of achieving a scripted replay?

Comment: First a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17563076/three-js-move-transition-and-sequence-action/17564159#17564159. If a tweening-based approach is not what you want, then consider creating a 3D path for each object and calling the function `getPointAt( t )` in each frame. See, for example the animation in http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_geometry_extrude_splines.html.

Comment: The Director.js script is certainly an option and I've already played with it. I'm not against a tweening-based approach at all but it just seemed like looping through data lists and chaining potentially thousands of tweens seems inefficient. Playback sounded like such a routine issue that I wondered if I'd missed something blindingly obvious. Thanks for the link to 3D paths though. I'll check that out now.

Comment: Maybe try TimelineLite from Greensock. http://www.greensock.com/sequence-video/. Docs: http://api.greensock.com/js/

Answer (score -1):

Table you present is a little misleading. Typically if you have a timeline, and number of objects is dynamic - you would create multiple timelines, one for each - this makes it easier to manipulate overall set.

```
var Record = function(time, value){
    this.time = time;
    this.value = value;
};
var Signal = function(){
    this.records = [];
    this.findValue = function(time){
        //... some divide and conquer implementation
    }
    this.getInterpolatedValue = function(time){...};
    this.add = function(time,value){
        //make sure sequence is preserved by doing a check or just assuming that add is always called with time greater than what's already in the series
        this.records.push(new Record(time,value));
    }
};

var signalObjA = new Signal();
var signalObjB = new Signal();
```

when it comes to replay, interpolation of some sort is necessary, and you probably want an animation manager of some sort, a thing which takes ( signal, object ) pairs and sets object values from signal based on current time.

```
var Binding = function(signal, object){
    this.signal = signal;
    this.object = object;
    this.applyTime = function(t){
       var val = this.signal.getInterpolatedValue(t);
       for(var p in val){
           if(val.hasOwnProperty(p)){
               this.object[p] = val[p]; //copying values into object
           }
       }
    }
}
var Simulator = function(){
    this.time = 0;
    this.bindings = [];
    this.step = function(timeDelta){
        this.time += timeDelta;
        var time = this.time;
        this.bindings.forEach(function(b){
            b.applyTime(time);
        });
    }
}
```

If you run into problems with space, try flattening `Record`s into a Float32Array or some other binary buffer of your choosing.

#### Edit:

please note that this approach is intended to save memory and remove data transformation. One saves on heap usage and GC, the other saves CPU time.

Comment: I'm curious as to why this is down-rated. The person in question has a timeseries data, not a single transition which can be handled by a tween of some sort. I would argue that using tween is exactly the wrong thing to do. If you were to draw a picture on the screen for a video, would you use 800*600 1pixel frame buffers and a timer for each to drive switching?